# How to check if a type is a struct from a portable library

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

Traditionally I would test if a type is a `struct` as such:

```
public void Do<TType>(TType value)
{  
   if (typeof(TType).IsValueType) 
   {
      // code for structs
   }
   else
   {
      // code for non structs
   }
}
```

But now I find the `IsValueType` property is not available in the portable class library with the frameworks I'm targeting. How would one go about to check if it is a struct or not then?

I'm targeting:

- .NET Framework 4.5
- ASP.NET Core 5
- Windows 8
- Windows Phone 8.1
- Xamarin.Android
- Xamarin.iOS
- Xamarin.iOS (Classic)

Comment: Based on @romanoza answer I found this link giving a technical explanation as to why it function like this. https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/11/29/typeinfo-reflection.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
using System.Reflection;

typeof(TType).GetTypeInfo().IsValueType
```